# How do I get the value in this neighboring element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having trouble with the jQuery part:

*HTML*

```
<div>
xxxxxxxxx
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><button class="addnum">xxxx</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>              
</div>

<div class="num">
    12345
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(".addnum").click(function() {
    var pur = $(this).siblings(".num").clone();
});
```

I'm trying to clone the value inside ".num", which is 12345.
How should I select it?

*edit: sorry, I didn't mention that I have multiple ".num" elements, and I have to only clone 1 at a time, there is a different value in each num, and I need to be able to select them individually. But Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `closest()`, `next()` and `parent()`:

```
var num =$(this).closest('div').parent().next(".num").text();
```

How it works:

```
<div><!-- parent of closest div of `.addnum` -->
    xxxxxxxxx
    <div><!-- closest div of `.addnum` -->
        <ul>
            <li>
              <button class="addnum">xxxx</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>               </div>
<!-- next `.num` to parent of closest div of `.addnum` -->
<div class="num">12345</div>
```

Comment: oh, wait, it worked! (deleted my previous comment) I made a typo in the code.. THANKS SO MUCH! I'll mark it as answer when the countdown ends

Comment: This is way too complicated and it'll break as soon as you make the slightest change to the HTML structure. I suggest you simply use a selector for the class of the div, that will always work.

Comment: thanks @CyberDude, but sorry I forgot to mention about having multiple values and only one should be selected at a time. Just edited the question. Thanks for all your helps

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$("div.num")`, you don't need to navigate the DOM with complicate selectors if your target element has a unique class or ID.

Comment: THANKS! but sorry I didn't mention in the question first that I have multiple ".num" elements with different values, and I need to only select one of them at a time. But yours will be useful in other scenarios. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

@Arvind, code should work.

However I would recommend you to wrap your HTML in a container and then use combination of [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for better maintainability.

```
 var pur = $(this).closest('.container').find(".num").text();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addnum").click(function() {
    var pur = $(this).closest('.container').find(".num").text();
    alert(pur)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    xxxxxxxxx
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button class="addnum">xxxx</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="num">
    12345
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By the way, I edited the question, I forgot to mention that I have multiple values with the class ".num", and I need to only select one at a time. thanks!

Comment: @tunping, I answered keep multiple values in mind and better maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

The button has no siblings, it's inside the UL and DIV elements. You could resort to moving up the DOM hierarchy (using parent() method and once you get to the right level, you select the element with class .num

`var num =$('.addnum').parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children('.num').text();`

That should give you the text inside the div.

Comment: CyberDude does have point, however. Using a container around the related elements or even better, related IDs is much better. You can also use data attributes to relate both elements so that fetching the .num element is more direct.